# Greater bond distance for silicon diamond structure than for carbon diamond structure?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, crystal-structure, covalent-compounds

In the silicon diamond structure the bond distance is about two times the bond distance of the carbon diamond structure. Is this caused only by the greater dimension of $\mathrm{Si}$ atoms with respect to $\mathrm{C}$ atoms? Or are there other reasons for a greater bond distance in the case of silicon?

Comment: How could you conclude that is not?  It is tricky to isolate bond length from atom size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both structures belong to the same [diamond cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_cubic) type, and the interatomic distances for [diamond](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/9012304.html) and [silicon](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/9011998.html) (you can use "Measurements" tool from the JSmol menu)

$$
\begin{align}
d(\ce{C-C}) &= \pu{1.54 Å} \\
d(\ce{Si-Si}) &= \pu{2.35 Å} \\
\frac{d(\ce{Si-Si})}{d(\ce{C-C})} &\approx 1.53
\end{align}
$$

are in a good agreement with the corresponding [covalent radii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_radius)

$$
\begin{align}
r_\mathrm{cov}(\ce{C}) &= \pu{0.76 Å} \\
r_\mathrm{cov}(\ce{Si}) &= \pu{1.11 Å} \\
\frac{r_\mathrm{cov}(\ce{Si})}{r_\mathrm{cov}(\ce{C})} &\approx 1.46
\end{align}
$$

which would set the silicon atoms further apart from each other.